# What is the best way to download bunch of .jar files from specific JFrog Artifactory using ansible script?

Tags: jar, ansible

What is the best way to download bunch of .jar files from specific JFrog Artifactory using ansible script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [get_url](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/get_url_module.html) module which handles basic auth and file retrieval from a URL. This can be combined with the `with_items` directive containing a list of your jar files.